# 13yo kid does not want to use knife for eating

Tags: behavior, eating

I have an unusual problem that is creating tense situations at home.  My 13y/o boy does not want to use his knife for eating.  He bends his head to the dish to eat things like salad or pasta. He prefers to eat big chunks of meat to avoid cutting it and when he cuts meat, he holds the knife with his whole fist.  To make it short, he eats like a savage or a 2 y/o.

The truth is that he seems to hate manual activities like writing, drawing.  His writing especially is that of a 5 y/o, and writing characters... upwards!

My problem is also worsened by the fact that whenever I get mad at his behaviour, my wife gets upset at me, not at him!

Is this lack of ease usual?  Can something be done about it?

Answer (score 3):

From what you describe, your son does not have the motor skills that are needed to handle a knife or a pen in the correct way. In that case, getting mad does not accomplish anything, except for creating a bad atmosphere at home.

For a 13 y/o to lack those motor skills is not normal and the issue should be addressed by a professional. Talk to your child's doctor about what options are available.